# Why are Berkovich spaces locally connected?

Tags: analytic-geometry, berkovich-geometry

A characteristic feature of [Berkovich spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkovich_space) is that they are locally connected (in fact, locally contractible). I'd like to understand the proof. The key ingredient seems to be Corollary 2.2.8 in Berkovich's [book](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Spectral_Theory_and_Analytic_Geometry_Ov/6x5PIl2-DkkC?hl=en). A key step in the proof is to take a connected component $W_n$ of a certain set $V_n$, but there is no explanation of why this connected component should be open (as I think it needs to be). I'd like to understand why.

**Question:** Why are Berkovich spaces locally connected?

Ideally, I'd appreciate a clarification of Berkovich's proof, or else a pointer to some other proof in the literature. Also, I'd be happy to understand the case of the Berkovich spectrum of a ring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X = \mathcal{M}(A)$ be an affinoid space. There is a map $\mathcal{M}(A) \to \operatorname{Spec}(A)$ sending a seminorm to its kernel. It is continuous, surjective and induces a bijection between the connected components of $\mathcal{M}(A)$ and $\operatorname{Spec}(A)$. Let me prove the last point.

First assume that $\operatorname{Spec}(A)$ is connected. Then $\mathcal{M}(A)$ is connected too. Indeed, consider a clopen subset $U$ of $\mathcal{M}(A)$. We can construct an analytic function $e$ on $\mathcal{M}(A)$ that is 0 on $U$ and 1 on the complement. But the global sections on $\mathcal{M}(A)$ are nothing but $A$ itself (Tate's theorem), so $e$ defines an element of $A$, which is idempotent. Since $\operatorname{Spec}(A)$ is connected, $A$ has only the trivial idempotents, so $e$ equals 0 or 1, hence $U$ is either the whole $\mathcal{M}(A)$ or the empty set.

For the general case, pick a connected component of $\operatorname{Spec}(A)$. It is a Zariski-closed subset of $\operatorname{Spec}(A)$, hence of the form $\operatorname{Spec}(B)$, with $B$ a quotient of $A$, so in particular an affinoid algebra. The previous argument shows that its preimage $\mathcal{M}(B)$ is connected. This finishes the proof of the bijection.

Finally, recall that the affinoid algebra $A$ is noetherian, so $\operatorname{Spec}(A)$ has finitely many connected components, and similarly for $\mathcal{A}$. As a consequence, those connected components are open.

I think this is what you need to complete the proof of local connectedness.

I am not sure what you mean about the Berkovich spectrum of a ring at the end of your post, so I will not comment on that.

Comment: I think that the Berkovich spectrum of a ring is simply the usual one, namely, the set of seminorms on a ring with weak topology. For example, $\mathcal M(\mathbb Z)$ looks like a star, with all archimedean and non-archimedean seminorms.

Comment: @Z.M: I am rather familiar with the construction but still not sure what the question is. Is $\mathcal{M}(A)$ locally connected for an arbitrary Banach ring $A$? Too general to be true I guess.

Comment: Thanks! I was indeed under the impression that $\mathcal M(A)$ should be locally connected for any discrete ring or Banach ring $A$, but I see now that it's important here to restrict to the affinoid case. So for example, the general theorem does _not_ explain the fact (also true, I think!) that $\mathcal M(\mathbb Z)$ is connected and locally connected.

Comment: Note to self: this answer shows that in the affinoid case, the connected components of $\mathcal M(A)$ are open in $\mathcal M(A)$. This doesn't compete the proof of local connectedness -- one needs to show that each point has a neighborhood basis of connected open sets. But that's exactly what Bekovich's 2.2.8 does.

Comment: @TimCampion I don't think $\mathcal{M}(A)$ should be locally connected in general, just as $\operatorname{Spec}(A)$ is not. Yes, $\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{Z})$ is connected and locally connected, which may be seen directly. Actually, all Berkovich spaces over $\mathbb{Z}$ are locally (path-)connected, see Théorème 7.2.17 in https://arxiv.org/abs/2010.08858.